# From July to August

Tags: phrase-usage, time

For example, if you will work somewhere starting on July 4th and ending on August 31st.

You work there for 2 months. But my question is:

Would you say:

1. > I work here until September

   *(meaning when September starts you don't work there anymore)*

OR

2. > I work here until August

   *(meaning whole August included)*

Comment: No, I don't think A and B are correct. What date is it now?

Comment: I suggest these two, "I had been working here until September" (if it happened in the past), or "I will be working here until September" (if it is going to happen)

Comment: This isn't really an English question, just a logical question. As with any other language, you just have to be more specific if you want to be sure you're understood correctly: "until the end of August", "until the start of September". But if I had to choose between one of the two proposed sentences I would say that "until September" gives the intended meaning because "until X" generally stops once X happens. And no particular reason to use the present progressive; it and the present simple would be equally good in my (Canadian) dialect.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I think it's even more a question of idiom. In spoken NAmE, you'll hear the present simple, present continuous, or future continuous in such contexts. To those who don't encounter actual spoken idiomatic English every day, though, the present simple is going to look odd, especially when it's written down.

Answer (score -1):

You can say:

- **"I am working here until (till) the end of August"** 
  or
- **"I am working here until (till) September 1"**. *(The day makes the sentence unambiguous)*

You could rephrase the second example to:

- **"I am working here till the 1st of September"**.
- **"I am working here till September the 1st"**.

You can also use **Going to**, the Future Simple or the Future Continuous.

Comment: What's wrong with the present simple here?

Comment: The present simple is perfectly idiomatic in both of the OP's examples. You are equally or slightly more likely to hear the present continuous or even the future continuous, but it's a coin flip.

Comment: _until the end of_ can be shortened and simplified to _through_: _I am working here through the end of August_. Also, I wouldn't mention September unless I was working there in September; I think "till September" is ambiguous.